# Retrieve scheme from Kafka for a topic Java

Tags: java

I am able to connect to Kafka and retrieve the data(serialized). However, I am unable to map it to scheme files (protobuf files). Is there a way to retrieve scheme definition for a topic from Kafka.

I am using below SimpleConsumer example from 
[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example)

Comment: Please post your code if you have written any to read the same.However complete example is already there in provided link to read the data.

Comment: I am using exactly the same code with my Kafka Config.